# Validation on form

Tags: javascript, validation

I repurposed some code for working out VAT, but I need to validate it not only for empty values but for values under 3,000,000. Javascript isn't really my forte, so I'm struggling to do something that seems rather basic. So far I have this:

```
<script language="javascript">

    // starts calculation
    function calculate() {
        var vat, total, vatTotal, finalTotal;

        var frm = document.calculator;

        total = evalnum(frm.total.value);
        if (total == "NaN")
            total = 0;
        if (total == 0) {
            alert("Please enter a valid ammount first.");
            frm.total.focus()
            return
        }
        else
            frm.total.value = evalpound(total);
        {
            vatTotal = total * 0.005;
            frm.calcvat.value = evalpound(vatTotal);
            frm.calctotal.value = evalpound(total + vatTotal);
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Scripts for VAT calculator
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var frm = document.calculator;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function selectBox(frmE, selectText) {

        var i;
        var selectIndex = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < document.calculator[frmE].length; i++) {
            if (document.calculator[frmE].options[i].value == selectText) {
                selectIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return selectIndex;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function evalnum(numstr) {

        var i, c, neg;
        var ret = "";
        var p = false;

        neg = 1;
        if (numstr.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
            neg = -1;
        }

        for (i = numstr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            c = numstr.charAt(i);

            if (c == ".") {
                if (p == false)
                    p = true;
                else
                    c = "";
            }

            if ((c < "0" || c > "9") && c != ".")
                c = "";

            ret = c + ret;
        }

        if (ret == "" || ret == "NaN")
            ret = "0";
        return parseFloat(ret * neg);

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function evalpound(num) {

        var i, l, d;
        var nums;
        var ret;

        nums = String(Math.round(num * 100));

        while (nums.length < 3)
            nums = "0" + nums;

        l = nums.length - 3;
        ret = "." + nums.charAt(l + 1) + nums.charAt(l + 2);

        d = 0;
        for (i = l; i >= 0; i--) {
            ret = nums.charAt(i) + ret;
            d++;
            if (d == 3 && i > 0) {
                ret = "," + ret;
                d = 0;
            }
        }

        ret = "£" + ret;
        return ret;

    }

</script>
```

HTML code is as follows.

```
    <form name="calculator">
<td class="calcbody" width="220" valign="top">Salary Bill:</td>
<td class="calcbody" width="150"><input type="text" class="calcinput" name="total" title
min="0" max format value size="9" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;"
onchange="calculate(this)"></td>
<tr>
<td width="100" height="22" class="calcbody" align="center"><a class="calcbutton"
href="javascript:calculate(this)">Calculate</a></td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="calcsubtitle"><b>Results</b></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="calcbody" valign="top">result</td>
<td class="calcbody"><input type="text" class="calcinput" name="calcvat"></td>
<td class="calcbody"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add the html form code too to identify the Ids

Comment: right, sorry, wasn't sure if everything was needed! edited with full form

Comment: Always post with a [mcve] of the relevant code. Too little is useless, but too much is overwhelming.

Comment: again sorry, very new to this so, stripped the HTML to bare minimum (ish)(thanks Roshana for suggested split)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. [Look at the errors](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) and fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The HTML works regardless (it's just old code). I was just inept at changing the .js

```
        total = evalnum(frm.total.value);
    if (total == "NaN")
        total = 0;
    if (total == 0) {
```

Became

```
        total = evalnum(frm.total.value);
    if (total == "NaN")
        total = 0;
    if (total < 3000000) {
```

I kept trying total == < 3000000 and stuff, instead of replacing the ==. As I said a very very basic change - Thanks for the help in any case :)